# <script>document.write('<base href=“' + document.location + '” />');</script>

Tags: xss, jsp-tags, fortify

I am getting cross-site Scripting: DOM critical issue. Please can anyone help with the alternateway of using document.write

```html
<script>
document.write('<base href=“' + document.location + '” />');
</script>
```

Comment: You are using curly quotation marks in your example instead of the straight ASCII ones, `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to prevent DOM XSS:

```html
<body>
<script>
document.body.innerHTML='<base href="' + encodeURI(document.location) + '" />';
</script>
</body>
```